# Can't read whole file in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to move content from one file to another.
My code:

```
    char *path = extractFileName(args[1]);
    if (path == 0)
        return -1;
    FILE *input = fopen(path, "r");

    rewind(input);
    fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long sz = ftell(input);
    printf("sz: %ld\n", sz);
    rewind(input);

    size_t a;
    FILE *result = fopen("result.mp3", "w");
    size_t counter = 0;
    char buffer[128];
    while ((a = fread(&buffer[0], 1, 128, input)) != 0) {
        fwrite(&buffer[0], 1, a, result);
        counter += a;
    }

    printf("%d\n", counter);
    printf("ferror input: %d\n", ferror(input));
    printf("feof input: %d\n", feof(input));
```

After execution it prints

```
sz: 6675688
25662
ferror input: 0
feof input: 16
```

As far as I know it means that C knows that size of input file is 665kb but returns eof when I try to read more than 25662 bytes. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried checking the ferror?  If there is one it might give you some insight.

Comment: I would not use `%d` to print `size_t`. And `&buffer[0]` is more commonly written `buffer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your output filename is `result.mp3`, it's a safe bet you're dealing with non-textual data. That means you should be opening your files in binary mode - `"rb"` and `"wb"` respectively. If you're running this code on Windows, not doing that would explain the behavior you're seeing (On that platform, reading a particular byte ([0x1A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character#End_of_file)) in text mode causes it to signal end of file even when it's not actually the end), and using binary mode will fix it. On other OSes, it's a no-op but still clues the reader into your intentions and the type of data you're expecting to work with, and is thus a good idea even if it's not strictly needed on them.